# Why redirect of no-www to www is not workng?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want that my website opens with both `mywebsite.com` and `www.mywebsite.com`. I've added the following lines to .htaccess (it's an Apache server).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

from [here](https://surtocriativo.com.br/redirecionando-url-site-ou-sem-www-usando-htaccess/), and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]
```

from [here](https://perishablepress.com/universal-www-canonicalization-via-htaccess/).

But when I type `mywebsite.com`, I'm still getting a "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site" error. Should I wait any longer before it starts working? Or what?

PS: There's a single line before it all:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Not sure if that matters.

Comment: "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site" is not a clear error message. What browser is that you are using? Sounds more like a name resolution issue to me.

Comment: @arkascha Firefox Quantum 68.0.2 (64-bit). "We can’t connect to the server at ..." is the error message right below. Also unclear.

Comment: And that is shown with what URL visible in the browser's address bar?

Comment: @arkascha "mywebsite.com", without the www.

Comment: Then the issue is not the redirection, but that the non-www host is not available. Check your name resolution and whether you have actually created a host for that name.